# IOS5 and facebook api

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I would like to integrate my app with Facebook and downloaded Facebook-ios-sdk from github. However, the sdk was for Xcode 4.0 code base - I am using Xcode 4.2 for iOS 5 beta 5 application... Is there a version of Facebook-ios-sdk for the latest iOS 5 beta? If there is, how can I download that?

Answer (score 4):

There is no specific version of Facebook-ios-sdk for the latest IOS 5 beta. Typically its good enough to download latest version of Facebook IOS SDK from [Git](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk). Complete reference to integrate Facebook sdk to your app is here. You can also walkthrough the Hackbook example.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

There is no version for iOS5 now. But you might want to use some new feature like ARC support.

But Facebook SDK was made by iOS4 and there is no ARC support. So you can do like this..

Just to add "-fno-objc-arc"(without double quotation marks) to the compiler flags for the files you don't want ARC. You can do this under your target -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources.

Answer (score 2):

I used this version of SDK for both my iOS 4& 5 successfully.

[Facebook sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

check this out: [rewrite the Facebook iOS client SDK into something that helped more than it hindered.](https://github.com/hiddenmemory/facebook-ios-sdk)