# Facebook SDK changes to Login in Pop-up view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook

I am Trying to Login my app with Facebook.For that reason I have Installed `Facebook SDK`. now Problem is I am trying to start with SAMPLEs code of SDK i.e `SessionLoginSample` .Problem is, to login Its takes me to the `SAFARI` to enter credientials.isn't it possible to open the login Page like PopUP View like(image 2)...

[image: enter the image] 
[image: enter the]
Image 1 is coming directly (SAFARI ) ..what changes required to open it like (image 2) pop up.

```
 - (IBAction)buttonClickHandler:(id)sender {

SLAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];


if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) {

    [appDelegate.session closeAndClearTokenInformation];

} else {
    if (appDelegate.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated) {

        appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
    }


    [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, 
                                                     FBSessionState status, 
                                                     NSError *error) {
        // and here we make sure to update our UX according to the new session state
        [self updateView];
    }];
} 
 }
```

Comment: are bhai tum kya chahte ho?? twitter ki tarah direct khule aisa??

Comment: ya right ..same like right image ...(not in safari)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use FBConnect for that see this bellow tutorial...

[iPhone-fbconnect-facebook-connect-tutorial](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-fbconnect-facebook-connect-tutorial/)

see the Login Dialog like bellow...

[image]

Just follow the instruction and create your id and use it..

Same but another tutorial with example see ...

[This](http://viksiphoneblog.blogspot.in/2010/10/iphone-fbconnect-facebook-connect.html)

Comment: ya buddy I have already tried.. but FBConeect is been Exprired it gives me the some msgs of expiring after login..even the official page is not been exist now... http://svn.facebook.com

Comment: hey try this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/ and also this one https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

Comment: ya same this I posted in question...its updated one ..but it opens fb in Safari..

Comment: which facebook-ios-sdk u used it??

Comment: oh and now in iOS6 i think here inbuilt framework of facebook like twitter.. i just here about it.. i not use facebooksdk from sometime so i have not more info about it but i will tell u if get somethoing about it

Comment: ya i know that its inbuilt in  iOS 6 fb,twitter ..but i can't upgrade it my existing project.. after that i will do..aniwys thanks..  :)

Comment: oye see this link may be you  get something from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493744/ios5-and-facebook-api

Comment: not much helpful :( ... chalo I will try to find ...u carry on :)

Comment: oh yaar ok i will post something if i got it.. and just check this some links in detail may be it will work ok dude...

Comment: @Christien have you try with share kit?

Comment: hey @Vishal give some links for that bro.. i think do something like this.. you have a latest idea with iOS 5 solution so dude.. :)

Comment: @Vishal ya i tried share kit..but its a combination of some apps ..and bit complicated to understand ..didnt the logic ...how to implement only for the Facebook only...

Comment: @Christien I know its a combination of some Apps but its not complicated You just ignore all other Apps...I think your problem will be solve with this...I often use share kit & what you need is easily achieve by share kit...see my given answer how is this achieve by share kit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250430/how-to-login-facebook-with-pop-up-view-not-through-safari-using-facebook-sdk-3/14250554#14250554

Comment: oh yes dude , but here for latest code for facebook i dont know for that so .. i think you solve this problem dude.. with ur above link answer

Comment: @Vishal ..Paras...http://i.imgur.com/ixNlE.png   fbConnect gives me the this error ..after login...did u try this??

Comment: and share kit is bit complicated ..it opens the links in the Actionsheet style...and many things it gives..i just want only the fb login

Comment: hey for that call direct code of facebook button click event of actionsheet .. try this.. just edit some code of that

Comment: ya I saw the code...Even In Sharekit FBConnect is been used for Facebook..but this does not gives any error ..if u use only FBConnect code ..it will give you the error

Comment: but try to add whole file which required for that and then import it just try it will work dude

Comment: @ParasJoshi bhai ho gaya vo fb login vo bi without safari.dimag kharab hua pada tha.nd bc sharekit ne usse bi jada dimag khaya tha..itna complicated tha nd itne feature h ki sirf fb use karne ke liye lag jaati...to finally i decided ki karunga to SDK mei hi change varna bhaad me jaye....and u won't belive Its a change of simple 2 lines only....uske liye itne dino se dimag kharab tha.. :)

Comment: @Vishal no prob yaar.  yaar problem was 1) fb has stopped supporting FBConnect 2)share kit was hard to apply 3) and even share kit uses FBConnect in his code...so that would be of no use..if i use share kit and again if it display the same msg

Answer (score 1):

Try using UIWebView. Following link may help.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app

Comment: ya thats what I wanted but I can't login properly from this... even I have entered my Facebook id..

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: `FBFun[769:f803] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> Application tried to present modally an active controller <FBFunViewController: 0x6a36ac0>.`

Comment: problem is in your View Structure. You have done something wrong in presenting the webview

Comment: I simply used the sample code ...didnt make any change ..and used my id

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for your session:

```
FBSession setActiveSession:[[FBSession alloc]initWithAppID:nil permissions:@[@"email", @"user_friends"] urlSchemeSuffix:@"foo" tokenCacheStrategy:nil]];
```

More information here: [Developers Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting)

Answer (score 0):

In XCode project in the file info.plist find or create row with key "FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix" and string value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this its working fine for me::

```
loginView.loginBehavior=FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView;
```

Here loginView is my FBLoginView.This is for your right side screen shot.

For Screen shot 1 use following code:

```
loginView.loginBehavior=FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingSafari;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  let loginView : FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()

  loginView.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.Web
```

It works for me, this is the source code in class FBSDKLoginManager:

```
public enum FBSDKLoginBehavior : UInt {

/*!
 @abstract Attempts log in through the native Facebook app. If the Facebook app is
 not installed on the device, falls back to \c FBSDKLoginBehaviorBrowser. This is the
 default behavior.
 */
case Native
/*!
 @abstract Attempts log in through the Safari browser
 */
case Browser
/*!
 @abstract Attempts log in through the Facebook account currently signed in through Settings.
 If no Facebook account is signed in, falls back to \c FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative.
 */
case SystemAccount
/*!
   @abstract Attemps log in through a modal \c UIWebView pop up

   @note This behavior is only available to certain types of apps. Please check the Facebook
   Platform Policy to verify your app meets the restrictions.
   */
case Web
```

}