# How to login facebook with pop up view, not through safari, using Facebook SDK 3.1?

Tags: iphone, facebook, authentication

Please help me this question! I want to create app login facebook, if device installed Facebook app, my app will call Facebook app when user login Facebook, if Facebook app is not installed, my app will show pop up login view, without sarafi?

Comment: It similar at link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214903/facebook-sdk-changes-to-login-in-pop-up-view

Comment: u got the way or not? bcz i found it..

Answer (score 2):

If You use share kit then Go to facebook.m class in your SDK find this method:

```
- (void)authorize:(NSArray *)permissions
         delegate:(id<FBSessionDelegate>)delegate
```

Then replace your last line which is:`[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES];`

With this line:`[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:NO;`  & check.

Comment: Sory..I'm using SDK facebook 3.1, not old SDK, I can't find facebook.m, I only find file.h..?? "share kit", what do you mean? sorry, i'm fresh man!

Comment: Then try with method that @Paras joshi tell in above link...

Comment: Ya actually I give answer according to old share kit implementation...

Answer (score 0):

This will handle opening a facebook session.

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                                  if (status == FBSessionStateOpen || status == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended)
                                  {
                                      NSLog(@"Logged in!");
                                  }
}];
```

Make sure your app delegate handles the callback url also.

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

Comment: where to use this `[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil` part .. I am using Facebook SDK SessionLoginSample Part...

Comment: Kris Jurgowski: Can you give me a sample code at "NSLog(@"Logged in!")"...at here, I can't code anthing..thanks!

Comment: Here's a way to print out your name: '[[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) { if (!error) { NSLog(@"%@", user.name) } }];'

Comment: I want to show pop up webview to login facebook...can I? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Facebook SDK you can use FBSession to open a session.

```
- (void)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {

// NSLog(@"openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:");

NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:

                        @"user_photos",
                        @"publish_actions",
                        @"read_stream",
                        @"friends_photos",
                        @"email" ,

                        nil];//You can add similar permissions according to your app.

[FBSession setActiveSession:[[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permissions]];

[[FBSession activeSession] openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView

                          completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,

                                              FBSessionState state,

                                              NSError *error) {

                              NSLog(@" state=%d",state);

                              // handle the completion handler...

                          }];
```

}

This will open the Facebook app if it is installed in your phone and will show the pop up if you are not logged in. It will use the safari if the native app is not installed in your device.

Before doing any action with Facebook always check whether the FBSession is open and active using: if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)